# Accessing Sqlite Database from Windows Forms Application in C++

Tags: c++, wpf, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

I am new to C++ (was previously into Java) and I am trying to find my way around it for the past few days. I am having a Sqlite DB in my local Machine which I am trying to access in order to display the results of a query on a Windows Application Form using DataGridView.

I was able to locate a good place to start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#code-snippet-1) but later discovered that this was more concentrated towards SQL server and not SQLite and the code failed when I tried to replace this part of code

```
String^ connectionString = 
                "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" +
                "Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost";
```

with this

```
String^ connectionString = "Data Source=C:\\data\\test.db"
```

to point to my local Sqlite DB (test.db).

Upon more digging I found that I was able to find C# examples for linking SQLite DB to Windows Form Application [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/988690/WinForms-WPF-Using-SQLite-DataBase). Next I tried to convert the C# code provided into a C++ one but failed.

I have been looking all around for simple C++ examples which would help me understand how to link a Sqlite DB to a Windows Form Application but am not able to do so yet.

I would appreciate it greatly if anyone could point me to one such example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access SQLite DB from managed code use [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) library. It's a managed library supported by SQLite Development Team and you can use it with managed C++ also. Here is the sample:

```
using namespace System::Data::SQLite;
using namespace System::Text;

void Test()
{
  SQLiteConnection ^db = gcnew SQLiteConnection();
  try
  {
    db->ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\\data\\test.db";
    db->Open();

    // Do the job here      

    db->Close();
  }
  finally
  {
    delete (IDisposable^)db;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I did manage to open the db and close it using a button but am facing a challenge when i try to link it to the DataGridView.

Comment: @SwaminathanIyer Nice to hear. If my answer is helpful to you, accept it please by ticking it on left side